# Get history for COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL

Tags: sql-server

I have a user database on SQL server Microsoft SQL Server 2017, but this specific database has a compatibility level of 100 (SQL Server 2008) instead of 140, which is the default.

Is it possible to find a date of changing level and user who did this? I've tried to filter SQL Server log by 'COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL', but unfortunately. I'm not sure that this is the correct way to check downgrade, but there are no ideas. I'm not sure also that this DB was created with this level.

Comment: If a databases compability level is changed, it is logged in the logs, with the event "Setting database option COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to {level} for database '{database name}". This does *not*, however, tell you who changed it. If you can't find that in any of your log files that suggests that either the database was always at that level, or it was changed prior to any of your log files.

Comment: Are you sure that it was ever at 140?  If the database was not newly created on the instance after SQL Server 2017 was installed then it's a good chance it never was at 140.  Compatibility level for a database is not automatically updated when a SQL Server instance is upgraded.  Nor is it set to the instance default when it's restored from backup (say, from an older version instance).